# javax.mail: not picking up properties

Tags: java, email, smtp, jakarta-mail

I'm trying to send an email message from the code to the smtp server which is not on localhost neither on default port 25.

I have a code which looks like:

```
// Set the host SMTP address
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.host", hostname);
props.put("mail.smtp.port", "8025");
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

// creates a new session with an authenticator
Authenticator auth = new Authenticator() {
    public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
    }
};
Session session = Session.getInstance(props, auth);

Transport trans = session.getTransport("smtp");

...piece of the code where message is created...

trans.send(message);
```

but it fails on `Transport.send()` with a timeout -1 error as is trying to connect to the localhost on port 25 but not to the host with the port specified above.

My question is how can I check existing properties (default localhost:25) or if there is any other Transport session already spawned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `send` method is static so it is using the session properties of the given message.  If you want to use the Transport you created you need to call [connect](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/javax/mail/Service.html#connect--), [sendMessage](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/javax/mail/Transport.html#sendMessage-javax.mail.Message-javax.mail.Address:A-), then [close](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/javax/mail/Service.html#close--).

```
// Set the host SMTP address
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.host", hostname);
props.put("mail.smtp.port", "8025");
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

// creates a new session with an authenticator
Authenticator auth = new Authenticator() {
    public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
    }
};
Session session = Session.getInstance(props, auth);

Transport trans = session.getTransport("smtp");

//...piece of the code where message is created...

trans.connect();
try {
   trans.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
} finally {
   trans.close();
}
```